# How can I resolve 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Version')' error while updating Azure Key Vault's secret expiration date in dotnet code?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-keyvault

Im trying to update the expiration date of the secret in Azure key vault from my dotnet code.
But Im getting this error on this calling method:  UpdateSecretPropertiesAsync().
Here is some related part of code:

```
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(_configuration[Constants.AZURE_TENANT_ID], _configuration[Constants.AZURE_CLIENT_ID], _configuration[Constants.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET]);

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(_configuration[Constants.KEY_VAULT_URL_UAT]), credential); 

var secretProperties = new SecretProperties(secretName);
secretProperties.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2);
client.UpdateSecretProperties(secretProperties);  // here im getting the error(Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Version'))
```

This is the documentation related to UpdateSecretPropertiesAsync: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.updatesecretproperties?view=azure-dotnet)

Can anyone please help me with this as I have very strict timelines.

Even though I tried to add

```
secretProperties.Version
```

but Version is readonly field.

Im Expecting this line of code to work but for some reason it is throwing the error. No idea why it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When updating a secret's properties, you're actually updating a specific version of the secret, not the secret as a whole.

So instead of

```
var secretProperties = new SecretProperties(secretName);
```

try fetch existing

```
KeyVaultSecret secretVersion = client.GetSecret(secretName);
var secretProperties = secretVersion.Properties;
```

Comment: @AfsarAF撒入 This approach is also allowed as it checks if a secret with a specific name already exists and adds a new version, otherwise create a new secret.

Comment: Anyhow I had done it in other way also as I have set the secret first. Here it is: `  var secretRestult = await client.SetSecretAsync(secretName, secret);
                client.UpdateSecretProperties(new SecretProperties(new Uri(secretRestult.Value.Id.AbsoluteUri)) { ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(2) });`